# Lotus Notes Attachment embodied within the body of the mail not as an attachment

Tags: email, lotus-notes, email-attachments, lotus

I've got a problem with Lotus Notes (apart from it's lotus notes), when we receive an e-mail with a csv attachment the attachment gets embodied into body of the message.

Is there any setting on the lotus server I can change to stop this from happening?

Anyone out-there with any ideas?

Comment: to clarify the attachment isn't showing as an attachment instead it's displayed as text in the body of the mail. How do I get it to show as an attachment instead?

Comment: Where do you get the attachment from? As far as I know, there is no setting in Lotus Notes / Domino, that does something like that... This has to happen at the sender or somewhere in the routing path

Comment: Where is the mail coming from? Another notes user? Or external email address?

Answer (score 0):

After over a week I've found out what the issue was. The email sender sent the email with a Context Description of inline rather then attachment thus lotus notes rather then notice that the file extension was csv took the inline factor literally.

Once I change the context description in notepad of the .msg file and resent the file it displayed correctly.