# VSTO (Outlook) is forcing MSG attachments to be of olEmbeddeditem type, but olByValue needed

Tags: outlook, vsto, lotus-notes, outlook-addin, msg

I need to send email with .msg file attached to Lotus Notes (Domino) by using VSTO (from Outlook Add-In). When this file is received in Lotus Notes, the email body from msg file is appended to the end of the main mail.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723974/lotus-notes-attachment-embodied-within-the-body-of-the-mail-not-as-an-attachment/19908781#19908781) problem I am assuming that the issue is in attachment type.
I am trying to set the attachment type to by **olByValue** by adding attachment :

```
mail.Attachments.Add(msgFilePath, OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 0, displayName);
```

but whatever type I specify, it is still set to **olEmbeddeditem**.

Is there any way, how to force msg attachment to be **olByValue**?

Thank you for any suggestion or advise.
Have a nice day.

Note: For reference I have created email in Lotus-Notes too with msg attached, sent to Outlook and than forwarded back to Lotus-Notes and msg is attached not appended to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much you can do in the Outlook Object Model - it always tries to be "helpful" and converts MSG files to embedded message attachments. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it will not change the type:

```
SafeMailItem sItem = new SafeMailItem();
sItem.Item = mail;
sItem.Attachments.Add(msgFilePath);
```

Comment: Tried, works. But actually, Redmption was not an option, due some internal policy - not white-listed (maybe yet?). At the end I have decided for workaround - to insert MSG into container (ZIP). There is no problem with setting olByValue for ZIP files.